# Quad Tree with Spatial data

Tags: java, spatial, quadtree

I am using the quadtree implemnted by [Ryan Pelletier's java-simple-quadtree on Github](https://github.com/ryanp102694/java-simple-quadtree) to read spatial data of Latitude and Longitude  and they are not being inserted in the tree. This is my data:

```
-73.807029724121094,40.699657440185547
```

and this is the search function of the QuadTree class

```
private List<RectangleObject> search(List<RectangleObject> rectangleObjects, RectangleObject rectangleObject){

        rectangleObjects.addAll(this.rectangleObjects);

        int index = getChildIndexRectangleBelongsIn(rectangleObject);
        //if the search area does not fit into any of the children perfectly
        if(index == QuadTree.THIS_QUADTREE || this.children[0] == null){
            //add anything that is on this QuadTree, may need to recurse down and add more
            if(this.children[0] != null){
                //for each of the children, if the search area overlaps with the child area, search the child
                for(int i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
                    if(GeometryUtil.rectangleObjectsOverlap(new SearchRectangleObject(Double.valueOf(this.children[i].getX()), Double.valueOf(this.children[i].getY()),Double.valueOf(this.children[i].getW()), Double.valueOf(this.children[i].getH())), rectangleObject)){
                        this.children[i].search(rectangleObjects, rectangleObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if(this.children[index] != null){
            //search area is in one of the children totally, but we still can't exclude the objects on this node, because that search area could include one
            this.children[index].search(rectangleObjects, rectangleObject);
        }
        return rectangleObjects;
    }
```

Comment: You have two main sections of code there 1. have you used a debugger to check that the data is actually been loaded correctly into the `searchRectangleObjects` array?  2. what is the `quadTree` as that seems to be critical to this problem but you didn't post the code.

Comment: 1. I didn't use the dubgger. 2- I added the GitHub link for the Quad Tree as the code is too long to post here is that okay ?

Comment: The debugger is THE most important tool at your disposal to diagnose these type of problems, otherwise you're just guessing what the problem which is tedious and time consuming.  I would **really** recommend trying it out, it's not hard.  If you can't post the quad tree code then you'll need to create a minimal example and post that, otherwise it's just guesswork and you won't get much help here.  As it is I suspect the problem is your quad tree is returning empty lists, but again I can't possibly prove that.

Comment: I added a snippet of QuadTree. As for debugging I am somewhat new to Eclipse and Java and I clicked the Debug as option but I did not see any result different from regular run. Is there another way to debug the code if you know. Thanks

Comment: The `search` method of quad tree is what you should have posted.  Suggest you look into unit-testing so you can verify individual parts of your code rather than trying to do everything at once (which is just a world of pain as I guess you can tell).  e.g. write a test to exercise the quad tree with a single element, then another with a parent-child, etc. to cover all the cases you can think.  For the debugger I can only suggest have a look online for tutorials or YouTube videos, you can use it to step through the code and find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The issue is when I use the code as is everything is fine ( I ran all the junit testing for the original Quad Tree) the issue is not in the quadtree it is only when I latitude and longitude data instead of the X and  y coordinates data that come with the original code. Here is the original data : 1980 5824. white my data is as mentioned above.

Comment: Quadtree implementation is notoriously difficult due to precision problems when recursively dividing by 2. Another option for debugging would be to use a different structure and see how that work. For example try the quadtree, R-Tree or kd-tree from [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) (shameless self advertisement).